# Vlookup for multiple images in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a Master sheet with all the details of the products, including its images. Currently, if I want to send a quotation or stock report to a customer according to their product requirements, here's how it goes -

- The customer sends me a list of product SKUs (item numbers)
- I create a new excel sheet and enter the product SKUs.
- Using Vlookup, I fill the other product details from the Master
  sheet. But for images, the Vlookup doesn't work. So, I would have to
  copy and paste the image of the corresponding product manually, for
  each product.

I want to automate this process.
I screen-recorded a short video of how I want it to work. Please check. [Link to video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPlyv.jpg)

As you can see, after I enter a product SKU in the second sheet, all the details gets filled automatically using vlookup, but for the images, I manually copy pasted it. So, I am looking for a VBA code, that automatically grabs the image from the Master sheet, corresponding to the product SKU and paste it in the cell, exactly like the vlookup, but for images. And also work for all the rows where the SKU is entered (just like how in vlookup, I just drag the formula down and it shows `#N/A` when there is no data in the first column, but once the data is there, it automatically fills the data from the Master sheet. I want the same thing for images).

So now, if I get a list of product's SKUs from a customer, I just have to enter it in the first column, and all the other details will be automatically filled including the images. This could save a lot of time for a large list of products.

I have also shown in the video that the image's name in the Master sheet is corresponding to the product SKU.

I hope I am illustrating my point correctly, and I apologize if my English is hard to understand.

Comment: Your question is so general, that no one can help you, even wanting to. So, a similar answer will be: yes, it is possible to do it using VBA. What workaround idea do you expect, since you did not say anything concrete about the problem. For instance:  are the picture names correlate somehow with the product you try offering? Is there only a picture per product? Do you know in which sheet, on which column such (a) picture(s) exist? What kind of picture are  you talking about (jpg, png etc.)? Do you  want placing the copied picture(s) in (a) specific place(s)? If so, where?

Comment: I apologize for not making my question clear. I have edited question and added more details. Kindly check and lmk. Thank you

Comment: Do you want a piece of code showing how to do it, or only ideas about the process? What does "The image names correlate with the product's SKU" mean? Is there in the master Sheet1 picture named **exactly** as its corresponding product? If you want copying them from the master, no other folder with pictures is necessary. But only if **the pictures inserting in it have names correlates with the product SKU**.  I mean, somebody changed their names after insertion. Usually Excel gives them names as `Picture1`, `Picture2` etc. If they are not named as they should, the can be imported from a folder.

Comment: Yes, the Master Sheet (Sheet1) with the product images has a corresponding SKU with the product's SKU. For instance, if a product's SKU is **123ABC**, then the image's name of that particular product is also named **123ABC**. So, I am looking for a VBA code that can vlookup the image by its name, and insert it into the Sheet2, with its corresponding product SKU..  Made an image for a small demonstration, kindly refer [link](https://imgur.com/a/1b9Njcq)

Comment: Then, please test the code I pasted. But take care to use your real worksheets instead of the code ones. I tested it using `ActiveSheet` instead of "Master" and next sheet instead of the one where to paste. If you want playing with the code **as it is*, an empty sheet must be added exactly after "Master" and have in its B:B column the SKU code which you try copying its picture...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next code. You should adapt `strSKU` for your real product code. But **that product code MUST exist in B:B of the sheet where the picture should be copied**:

```
Sub copyPicturesFromMaster()
   Dim wsM As Worksheet, wsOf As Worksheet, sh As Shape, shP As Shape, strSKU As String, rngSKU As Range
   
   strSKU = "123ABC"      'use here your SKU code
   Set wsM = ActiveSheet  'use here your master sheet (maybe Worksheets("Master")
   Set wsOf = wsM.Next     'use here the sheet where you need to paste the copied picture
   
   For Each sh In wsM.Shapes 'iterate between master sheet shapes:
        If TypeName(sh.OLEFormat.Object) = "Picture" And sh.name = strSKU Then 'if its name is the searched SKU and is a Picture
            'find the cell where the SKU product code exists (in B:B):
            Set rngSKU = wsOf.Range("B:B").Find(What:=strSKU, After:=wsOf.Range("B2"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not rngSKU Is Nothing Then  'if it has been found:
                sh.Copy: wsOf.Paste                'copy - paste the necessary shape
                
                Set shP = wsOf.Shapes(wsOf.Shapes.count) 'set the last copied sheet
                shP.left = rngSKU.Offset(, 1).left 'move it in the right place
                shP.top = rngSKU.Offset(, 1).top
            Else
                MsgBox "Product """ & strSKU & """ could not be found in B:B column..." 'if no SKU code in columln B:B
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
   Next sh
   Debug.Print TypeName(Selection)
End Sub
```

**Edit**:

The next version event code does not need any `Vlookup` formulas. Anyhow, it is better to copy the sheet without formulas targeting a non existing workbook:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wsM As Worksheet, wsOf As Worksheet, sh As Shape, shp As Shape, strSKU As String
    Dim sHeight As Double, sWidth As Double, rngProduct As Range, i As Long
    
    If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Target.column = 1 Then
        If Target.cells.count > 1 Then MsgBox "This code works only for a single cell (in column A:A) modification)!": Exit Sub
        Set wsM = Worksheets("Sheet1")  'use here your master sheet
        Set wsOf = Me                   'the active sheet (this one)
        'find the product code introduced in the offer sheet:
        Set rngProduct = wsM.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Target.Value, After:=wsM.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If rngProduct Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No product """ & Target.Value & """ found in the master sheet": Exit Sub
        
        'Copy the fields brought until now using Vlookup:
        Application.EnableEvents = False
         For i = 2 To 4 'it copies the next three columns after B:B. If more columns necessary to be copied, increas from 4 to  necessary
              Target.Offset(, i).Value = rngProduct.Offset(, i).Value
         Next i
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        
        'format C:C column as text (even aleready having numbers formatted as scientifique:
        Me.UsedRange.Columns(3).EntireColumn.TextToColumns FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2)

        For Each sh In wsM.Shapes 'iterate between master sheet shapes:
             If TypeName(sh.OLEFormat.Object) = "Picture" And sh.name = Target.Value Then 'if its name is the searched SKU and is a Picture
                     sh.Copy:                     'copy  the necessary shape
                    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
                    wsOf.Paste
                    Set shp = wsOf.Shapes(wsOf.Shapes.count) 'set the last copied/created shape
                                      
                     sHeight = shp.height: sWidth = shp.width 'extract initial height and width
                     
                     'determine which dimension should be diminished, to be sure that both of them are inside the cell:
                     If shp.height < Target.Offset(, 1).height And shp.width < Target.Offset(, 1).width Then
                                If shp.height > shp.width Then
                                  shp.height = Target.Offset(, 1).height - 2
                                  If shp.width > Target.Offset(, 1).width Then shp.width = Target.Offset(, 1).width
                                  sWidth = shp.width: sHeight = shp.height
                            Else
                                 shp.width = Target.Offset(, 1).width - 2
                                 If shp.height > Target.Offset(, 1).height Then shp.height = Target.Offset(, 1).height
                                 sWidth = shp.width: sHeight = shp.height
                            End If
                     ElseIf shp.height < Target.Offset(, 1).height And shp.width > Target.Offset(, 1).width Then
                               shp.width = Target.Offset(, 1).width - 2: sWidth = shp.width: sHeight = shp.height:: sWidth = shp.width
                     ElseIf shp.height > Target.Offset(, 1).height And shp.width > Target.Offset(, 1).width Then
                            If shp.height > shp.width Then
                                  shp.height = Target.Offset(, 1).height - 2
                                  If shp.width > Target.Offset(, 1).width Then shp.width = Target.Offset(, 1).width
                                  sWidth = shp.width: sHeight = shp.height
                            Else
                                 shp.width = Target.Offset(, 1).width - 2:
                                 If shp.height > Target.Offset(, 1).height Then shp.height = Target.Offset(, 1).height
                                 sWidth = shp.width: sHeight = shp.height
                            End If
                     End If
                     
                     'set the correct top and left, to be centered on cell:
                      shp.top = Target.Offset(, 1).top + (Target.Offset(, 1).height - sHeight) / 2
                      shp.left = Target.Offset(, 1).left + Target.Offset(, 1) + (Target.Offset(, 1).width - sWidth) / 2
                     Exit For
             End If
        Next sh
    End If
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249878/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-vlookup-for-multiple-images-in-excel).